# How to make iso attached to VMware Workstation available to nested vm?

Tags: linux, rhel, kvm, vmware-workstation, nested-virtualization

Im thinking how to make things easier, namely I would like to know if there is any possibility to make i.e rhel8.iso attached to VMware Workstation available to guest OS inside. I want use kvm inside guest OS (RHEL 8). I know about solution like i.e dd if=/dev/sr0 of=./rhel.iso and then using it as iso image, however it is doubled work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I just check, please. You have VMware Workstation running a client, which is actually acting as host for another virtual machine...?

Comment: VMware Workstation is installed on my physicall host then on top of it sits RHEL8 guest OS to which is attached rhel8.iso. My question is how to make it available to nested vm inside RHEL8

Comment: I presume the nested VM can simply use `/dev/cdrom`.

Comment: Map the physical drive through to your RHEL VM. Then on that VM-as-host map the "physical" drive through to the nested VM. What's the problem?

Comment: Dont know what do you mean by mapping. I dont have to map anything the .iso attached to VMware is available under /dev/sr0 which is /run/media/user/....; however its no longer iso but raw file(decompressed) different format, that indeed was my question. For this reason I need to use aforementioned command dd in the first place but wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No it cannot use /dec/cdrom due to the above reason

Comment: https://imgur.com/zPW44Rw

Comment: @Bartosz Looks like it's a RHEL limitation. Please ask their support how to deal with it and Google for: *RHEL driver host_cdrom is not whitelisted*